# CSS: change color of png when hover + select

Tags: css

I am quite new to CSS and I am trying to reproduce this example with Cloud Providers (GCP, Azure or AWS).

[image]

This is what I have so far and I am struggling to make a `li` item from that list blue (`img + border`) whenever that `li` is selected or when `:hover`.

[image]

**html**

```
  <ul className="cloud-list">
    <li>
      <div className="logo-container">
      <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "images/aws.png"} alt="logo" />
      </div>
      <h4>Amazon Web Services</h4>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div className="logo-container">
      <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "images/gcp.png"} alt="logo" />
      </div>              <h4>Google Cloud Platform</h4>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div className="logo-container">
      <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "images/azure.png"} alt="logo" />
      </div>              <h4>Microsoft Amzure</h4>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**css**

```
 .cloud-list{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;    
  }

  .cloud-list li{
    border-radius: 5%;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 9px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 9px #999;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 9px #999;
  }

  .cloud-list .logo-container{
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

.cloud-list li img{
  margin: auto;
  width: 180px;
  height: auto;
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
  filter: grayscale(1); /* Microsoft Edge and Firefox 35+ */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this to set the border:

```
.cloud-list li:hover,
.cloud-list li:focus,
.cloud-list li:active {
    border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

Comment: And just add `filter: grayscale(0)`  for the image to be blue on hover...

Comment: Do you know what should I do to keep track of which li is active (selected?)

Comment: easy way here is to add some click event to your li tags (and make it focusable for accessibility) <li tabindex="0" onclick="window.location='http://my-site.com/my-page.html'">